# How can I make typeclass about convertibility?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

```hs
class Convertible a b where
    convert :: a -> b

instance {-# OVERLAPPABLE #-} (Convertible a b, Convertible b c) => Convertible a c where
    convert = convert . convert             -- this is illegal


data Complex = Complex Float Float;
data Matrix2D = Matrix2D Float Float Float Float;
data Vector2D = Vector2D Float Float;

instance Convertible Complex Matrix2D where
    convert (Complex r i) =
        Matrix2D r (-i) i r

instance Convertible Complex Vector2D where
    convert (Complex r i) =
        Vector2D r i

instance Convertible Vector2D Complex where
    convert (Vector2D x y) =
        Complex x y

instance Convertible Float Matrix2D where
    convert x =
        Matrix2D x 0 0 x
```

I'm making `Convertible` typeclass for practice. It is typeclass about convertibility between a to b. The definition of `convert` is illegal because type `b` is could not be deduced from function call. How can I make `Convertible` works / or make similar typeclass?

Comment: You're not going to be able to do this kind of indirect conversion without something telling it what chain of types to convert though. It's just fundamental to how type classes work that the compiler will not be able to guess the middle of the path for you, and it would be a bad idea even if it could. In the general case there could be multiple paths to convert from type A to type B with different results depending on what's used in the middle. You could try adding a type level list of the conversion steps, which you might be able to leave inferred when doing a simple one step conversion?

Comment: Take a look at the "Why a single instance is not enough" box in the [Safe Zero-cost Coercions for Haskell](https://www.seas.upenn.edu/~sweirich/papers/coercible.pdf) paper.

Comment: I think between that and https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC/AdvancedOverlap you could probably hack together something that at least sort of works. I'll try myself for a while and write up an answer if I'm successful.